# VBA parse string Place values to new columns

Tags: parsing, excel, replace, split, vba

I have a sheets with the rows of data like.

```
NOM(LSL,USL)=207.3980(206.1990,208.5970)    NOM(LSL,USL)=207.3980(206.1990,208.5970)    NOM(LSL,USL)=18.8200(18.4400,19.2100)
```

I would like to just grab the Values and place them in their own cells like

```
207.3980    207.3980    18.8200
206.1990    206.1990    18.4400
208.5970    208.5970    19.2100
```

I continue to recieve "ByRef Argument Mismatch" errors. I believe relating to how I am defining the reference cell.

```
Sub Parse_Replace()
        Dim i As Double
        Dim ws As Worksheet
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        Dim Col As Range
        Dim rLastCell As Range
            Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    For i = rLastCell.Column To 1 Step -1
        Col = ColLett(rLastCell.Column)
        Columns(i).Cells(4) = SplitString(Col3, ",", 4)
        Columns(i).Cells(5) = SplitString(Col3, ",", 5)
        Columns(i).Cells(6) = SplitString(Col3, ",", 6)
    Next i

    End Sub

Function ColLett(Col As Integer) As String

    If Col > 26 Then
        ColLett = ColLett((Col - (Col Mod 26)) / 26) + Chr(Col Mod 26 + 64)
    Else
        ColLett = Chr(Col + 64)
    End If

    End Function

Function SplitString(pValue As String, pChar As String, pIndex As Integer) As Variant
    Dim YString As Variant

        YString = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(pValue, " ", ""), "=", ""), "(", ","), ")", ",")
        SplitString = Split(YString, pChar)(pIndex - 1)

    End Function
```

**Process**

- Establish number of Columns with Data
- Loop through each column

  - Convert column index to Column with `ColLett`
  - Set cell value with `SplitString`
- Loop

Thank You

**EDIT :** replaced `SplitString` value with inteded.

Comment: On which line are you receiving the error?

Comment: `Columns(i).Cells(4) = SplitString(B3, ",", 4)`

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume that the **NOM(LSL,USL)** text is not the same throughout all of the rows?

Comment: @Jeeped, It is the same across all columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `Col` to be a range here:

```
Dim Col As Range
```

You then try to set `Col` to a string here:

```
Col = ColLett(rLastCell.Column)
```

When you set a range you have to set it to a range. Furthermore, you have to use the `SET` keyword to do so:

```
Set Col = <a range>
```

When you set that `Col` you set it only to the `rLastCell.Column` repeatedly in each loop of your `For`. If you just need that column letter for the last column, then do it before entering your for loop.

All of that is pointless anyway. At no point do you use the Column letter that you went through the trouble retrieving in your function. And really, for what you are doing you don't need the Column Letter. Column Letters are for humans; the column number is what is important in VBA any how.

Comment: When passing arguments to `SplitString` It is going to be looking for column by letter?  Can I modifiy that function to us `rLastCell.Column` as it is?

Comment: Ah. Another strange thing here then. Your call to SplitString sends variable Col3 which is not declared and never set. So... the bit I mentioned above will cause an error, once you fix the problem with `Col3` variable. What is `Col3` supposed to be?

Comment: Col needs too update to the current column so that is parses the correct data.

Comment: I think that I am calling it incorrectly. In this case Col3 = B3, but Col needs to update to the correct column for the loop.

Comment: But you don't want to pass "B3" as a string down to the SplitString function. You want to send the String that is in RANGE `B3`. `B` being the column you are iterating through, right? So before you call `SplitString` put the line `Col3=ws.cells(3,i).value`  Now `Col3` which has to be a string according to the `splitstring` function parameters, is now properly set to the big string you are wanting to parse.  Then you can get rid of the Column Letter logic since it's not needed here.

Comment: I have a bug, As it runs it is trimming off digits. Trailling zeros. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: That's Excel's "friendly" front end guessing that these are numbers, not text.  Change the return type of `splitstring` to `STRING` instead of `VARIANT`, then, before you call it, set the cell format to `text`. So before `Columns(i).Cells(4) = SplitString(Col3, ",", 4)` use a line like `Columns(i).Cells(4).NumberFormat = "@"`. It might also help to do a chant, encantation, or rain dance afterwards too, as Excel really likes to change formats.